# Masking numbers in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to change a text that contains numbers. The first and the last character of the numbers need to remain, the others should be replaced by a `*`. Numbers mixed up with text should remain unchanged.

I have this code:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=[\d]{1})[\d]*(?=[\d]{1})", 
                              m => new string('*', m.Length));
```

That with this input:

```
"Lorem 1 ip234sum 22 dolor 3234445 sit amet, adipiscing 1234"
```

Should show this result:

```
"Lorem 1 ip234sum 22 dolor 3*****5 sit amet, adipiscing 1**4"
```

However, the current output is:

```
"Lorem 1 ip2*4sum 22 dolor 3*****5 sit amet, adipiscing 1**4"
```

As you see it incorrectly also operates on `ip234sum`. How can I make it ignore parts of the string that are not entirely numeric?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `\b` anchors to your look-arounds will fix the problem:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\b[\d]{1})[\d]*(?=[\d]{1}\b)", m => new string('*', m.Length));
//                                         ^^                       ^^
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/a6jIGX)

Comment: The `(?<=\b\d)\d+(?=\d\b)` regex is much cleaner.

Comment: @stribizhev That is absolutely true. However, I wanted to keep as much of OP's expression intact, because he was so close to a right solution. He may have reasons to keep the `{1}`: perhaps he wanted an ability to change the number of "visible" characters - say, two on each side.